# What python package can translate Greek letter to ASCII requivalent?

Tags: python, python-unicode

`unidecode` translates `μ` to `m`. But I'd like `mu` instead. Is there a python package that can do so (also for other Greek letters)?

```
>>> import unidecode
>>> unidecode.unidecode(u'μ')
'm'
```

Comment: Why not make a dictionary that maps each character to the name you want to use?

Comment: `import unicodedata; unicodedata.name('μ').split()[-1].lower()` :P

Comment: @L3viathan Why don't you post this as an answer? Maybe also check whether there is `SMALL` in the name and either use `lower()` or `title()` accordingly.

Comment: @tobias_k I guess so. Also asserted it's actually greek; bad surprises ahead otherwise^^

Answer (score 4):

I guess it works™:

```
import unicodedata

def greek_to_name(symbol):
    greek, size, letter, what, *with_tonos = unicodedata.name(symbol).split()
    assert greek, letter == ("GREEK", "LETTER")
    return what.lower() if size == "SMALL" else what.title()
```